# Is it poor design to use static fields to limit the amount of constructor parameters if most of those parameters are shared?

Tags: c#

Would it be poor design to implement the proposed logic below? Essentially, the goal is to limit the number of times I'm passing in shared parameters

```
**// Current implementation**
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration(Foo f, Bar b, Baz bz, Qux q, FooBar fb);
    public Configuration(Foo f, Bar b, Baz bz, Qux q, BazQux bz);
}


Main
{
  var configA = new Configuration(f, b, bz, q, fb)
  var configB = new Configuration(f, b, bz, q, bz)
  DoStuff(configA);
  DoOtherStuff(configB);
}

**// Proposed implementation**
public class Configuration
{
    static Foo f;
    static Bar b;
    static Baz bz;
    static Qux q;
    public Configuration(FooBar fb);
    public Configuration(BazQux bz);
}

Main
{
  Configuration.Foo = f; 
  . . . 
  var configA = new Configuration(fb)
  var configB = new Configuration(bz)
  DoStuff(configA);
  DoOtherStuff(configB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's a bad design. what if you'll need to create a different configuration configC which uses a different Foo instance?